# Using Route Parameters in Razor Pages to Display value of ID

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax, .net-6.0, razor-pages

I'm currently using an input textbox and a button to display the value entered from a database using a partial view as shown in the images below

[image]

[image]

Index.cshtml

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{ ViewData["Title"] = "Index"; }

<form method="get">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBox("TxtDepartment")
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" id="DepartmentSearch">Search</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<br />

<table>
    <tr>
        <td><div id="DepartmentResult"></div></td>&nbsp;
        <td><div id="EmployeeResult"></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<form method="get">
    <label>Department Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="DeptName" />
    <label>Photo File Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="NameResult" />
</form>

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $("#DepartmentSearch").click(function()
        {
            $.ajax(
            {
                url: "/Index?handler=DisplayDepartment",
                type: "GET",
                data: { value: $("#TxtDepartment").val() },
                headers: { RequestVerificationToken: $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
                success: function(data) { $("#DepartmentResult").html(data); }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Index.cshtml.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using PracticeApp.Models;
using System.Linq;

namespace PracticeApp.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public CompanyContext _context;

        public IndexModel(CompanyContext context) { _context = context; }

        public PartialViewResult OnGetDisplayDepartment(int value)
        {
            return Partial("_DisplayDepartmentPartial", _context.Departments.Where(x => x.DepartmentId == value).ToList());
        }
```

What I'm trying to do is instead of using a textbox and button, I want the Property ID value in the URL as when the page loads have the partial view load based on the value in the URL

This is my Department model

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace PracticeApp.Models
{
    public partial class Department
    {
        [Display(Name = "ID")] public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Name")] public string DepartmentName { get; set; } = null!;
    }
}
```

I've tried @page {id?} but I' stuck on the AJAX portion

[image]

[image]

Comment: So the index page has an id parameter? Then you need to bind that value to a property (or method argument) of the index page. `[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)] public int Id { get; set; }` Then you don't need ajax, since the index page can directly output the partial view.

Comment: In other words, I would turn `_DisplayDepartmentPartial` into a page, with a `Layout` for the surrounding html.

Comment: I was thinking that as well, but if I do

var result = _context.Departments.Where(x => x.DepartmentId == value).ToList();

return Page();
this will not work

Comment: You need to load the department into a model property, so your view can `<partial model="@Model.Result" ...`

Comment: ```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace PracticeApp.Models
{
    public partial class Department
    {
        [Display(Name = "ID")] public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Name")] public string DepartmentName { get; set; } = null!;
    }
}
```

this is my Model

Comment: `IndexModel` is the model (and handlers) of your `Index.cshtml`, if you need to pass parameters from your handler to your view (/page), stick them in a property of the model.

Comment: can you put this as an answer? i'm confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

Index.cshtml.cs:

Create an Id property to receive the parameters in the url:

```
[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public int Id { get; set; }

public PartialViewResult OnGetDisplayDepartment(int value)
{
    return Partial("_DisplayDepartmentPartial", _context.Departments.Where(x => x.Id == value).ToList());
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@page "{id?}"
...
@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax(
                {
                    url: "/Index?handler=DisplayDepartment",
                    type: "Get",
                    data: { value: @Model.Id },
                    headers: { RequestVerificationToken: $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
                    success: function (data) { $("#DepartmentResult").html(data); }
                });
        })
        $("#DepartmentSearch").click(function () {
            $.ajax(
                {
                    url: "/Index?handler=DisplayDepartment",
                    type: "Get",
                    data: { value: $("#TxtDepartment").val() },
                    headers: { RequestVerificationToken: $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
                    success: function (data) { $("#DepartmentResult").html(data); }
                });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Test Result:

[image]

Comment: my friend you have come through for me once again, thanks

Comment: Hi @Chen, can you take a look at this question for me?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74552265/autofill-input-textboxes-from-clicking-a-hyperlink-on-a-partial-view

Comment: Hi @TheGame1083, sorry to see your message so late. I have looked at your question and Rena's answer is correct, when clicked you need to fetch data from PageModel via ajax and pass back to Page for filling. Can you describe your problem a bit more clearly?

Comment: Hi @Chen, I have updated the code in my original question from the link to include all the models, I'm still having trouble fetching and passing back the values based on my image in the question