# Autofill input textboxes from clicking a hyperlink on a partial view

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, razor-pages

please refer to the image, when I click on the link on the left partial table, instead of having the values display on a separate partial table view as shown, I'd like the values to be autofilled in the bottom 2 textboxes to avoid having to click and drag the values and to have the date formatted to 01312000 format

index.cshtml

```
@page "{id?}"
@model IndexModel

@{ViewData["Title"] = "Test";}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="text-center">
            <h1 class="display-4">@Model.PageTitle</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <form class="mt-0" method="get">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-3 offset-1" id="ApplicationResult">
                </div>
                <div class="col-4" id="ApplicationOwnerResult">
                </div>
                <div class="col-3" id="ApplicationDmvResult">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <form class="mt-0" method="post">
            <div class="row">
                <label class="col-2 offset-4 col-form-label">Date of Birth:</label>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <input class="form-control" title="Date of birth" oninput="validate()" asp-for="DateOfBirth">
                    <span asp-validation-for="DateOfBirth"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
                <label class="col-2 offset-4 col-form-label">Driver's License Number:</label>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <input class="form-control" title="Driver's license number" oninput="validate()" asp-for="DriversLicenseNumber">
                    <span asp-validation-for="DriversLicenseNumber"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-dark col-1 offset-5" type="submit" id="Submit" disabled asp-page-handler="Submit">Submit</button>
                &nbsp;
                <button class="btn btn-outline-dark col-1" type="button" id="Reset" onclick="clearAll()">Reset</button>
            </div>
            <br>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
<script>
// Any exemption applications found will be displayed when the page initially loads. On POST request GET form will be hidden
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ("@Model.Exist" == "DivIsVisible") {
            $.ajax({
                url: "Index/?handler=Display",
                type: "GET",
                data: { value: @Model.Id },
                headers: { RequestVerificationToken: $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
                success: function (data) { $("#ApplicationResult").html(data); }
            });
        }
        else {
            $("#ApplicationResult").hide();
        }
    });
</script>
}
```

index.cshtml.cs

```
using DMVServiceReference;
using DMV.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DMV.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public Assess50Context _context;

        // Id property refers to checking the PropertyId value for the URL
        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)] public int Id { get; set; }
        // Exist property refers to checking if GetDivs exist on POST request
        [BindProperty] public string PageTitle { get; set; } = "Residency Check";
        public ResidencyCheckCriteria CheckCriteria { get; set; }
        [BindProperty, DataMember, MaxLength(8, ErrorMessage = " "), MinLength(8, ErrorMessage = " "), RegularExpression(@"^([0-9]{8}$)", ErrorMessage = " "), Required(ErrorMessage = " ")] public string DateOfBirth { get => CheckCriteria.DateOfBirth; set => CheckCriteria.DateOfBirth = value; }
        [BindProperty, DataMember, MaxLength(13, ErrorMessage = " "), MinLength(13, ErrorMessage = " "), RegularExpression(@"^([A-Za-z0-9]{13}$)", ErrorMessage = " "), Required(ErrorMessage = " ")] public string DriversLicenseNumber { get => CheckCriteria.DriverLicenseNumber; set => CheckCriteria.DriverLicenseNumber = value; }
        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)] public string Exist { get; set; } = "DivIsVisible";

        public IndexModel(Assess50Context context)
        {
            _context = context;
            CheckCriteria = new ResidencyCheckCriteria();
        }

        // Reads all exemption application table information by property id
        public PartialViewResult OnGetDisplay(int value) => Partial("_DisplayApplicationPartial", _context.ExemptionApplications.Where(x => x.PropertyId == value).ToList());

        // Reads all exemption application owner information by exemption application id
        public PartialViewResult OnGetDisplayOwner(int value) => Partial("_DisplayOwnerPartial", _context.ExemptionApplicationOwners.Where(x => x.ExemptionApplicationId == value).GroupBy(x => x.ExemptionApplicationOwnerId).Select(x => x.First()).ToList());

        // Reads the dmv information by application owner ID
        public PartialViewResult OnGetDisplayOwnerInfo(int value) => Partial("_DisplayDMVPartial", _context.ExemptionApplicationDmvinformations.Where(x => x.ExemptionApplicationOwnerId == value).ToList());
```

DbContext.cs

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace DMV.Models
{
    public partial class Assess50Context : DbContext
    {
        public virtual DbSet<ExemptionApplication> ExemptionApplications { get; set; } = null!;
  public virtual DbSet<ExemptionApplicationDmvinformation> ExemptionApplicationDmvinformations { get; set; } = null!;
 public virtual DbSet<ExemptionApplicationOwner> ExemptionApplicationOwners { get; set; } = null!;

 public Assess50Context() {}

        public Assess50Context(DbContextOptions<Assess50Context> options) : base(options) {}

 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
  }

        partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Application.cs model

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace DMV.Models
{
    public partial class ExemptionApplication
    {
        public int PropertyId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Year")] public short YearId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "App ID")] public int ExemptionApplicationId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Reference Number")] public string? ApplicationReference { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Owner.cs model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace DMV.Models
{
    public partial class ExemptionApplicationOwner
    {
        public int PropertyId { get; set; }
        public int ExemptionApplicationId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Application Owner ID")] public int ExemptionApplicationOwnerId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Owner ID")] public int? OwnerId { get; set; }
        public string? FirstName { get; set; }
        public string? LastName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Name")]public string? AssessProName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

DmvInformation.cs model

```
using SoapCore.ServiceModel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace DMV.Models
{
    public partial class ExemptionApplicationDmvinformation
    {
        public int PropertyId { get; set; }
        public int ExemptionApplicationId { get; set; }
        public int ExemptionApplicationOwnerId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "DOB")] public DateTime? DmvDob { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Driver's License #")] public string? DriverLicense { get; set; }
    }
}
```

_DisplayApplicationPartial.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.ExemptionApplication>

@if (Model.Count() != 0)
 {
    <div id="ExemptionApplicationNav">
        <table class="PartialTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="PartialTableRowData" colspan="3">Exemption Applications</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="PartialTableRowCategoryData">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.YearId)</td>
                    <td class="PartialTableRowCategoryData">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.ApplicationReference)</td>
                    <td class="PartialTableRowCategoryData">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.ExemptionApplicationId)</td>
                </tr>
                @foreach (Models.ExemptionApplication item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td class="PartialTableRowData">@item.YearId</td>
                        <td class="PartialTableRowData">@item.ApplicationReference</td>
                        <td class="PartialTableRowData">
                            <a class="DMVLabelsTexts" href="Index/?handler=DisplayOwner&value=@item.ExemptionApplicationId">@item.ExemptionApplicationId</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
 }
else
{
    <p>No exemption applications found for this Property ID</p>
}
    <script>
        $('#ExemptionApplicationNav a').click(function (e) {
            $('#ApplicationOwnerResult').hide().load($(this).attr('href'), function () {
                $('#ApplicationOwnerResult').show()
            })
            return false
        })
    </script>
```

_DisplayOwnerPartial.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.ExemptionApplicationOwner>

@if (Model.Count() != 0)
{
    <div id="OwnerNav">
        <table class="PartialTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="PartialTableRowData" colspan="3">Owner Information</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="PartialTableRowCategoryData">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.ExemptionApplicationOwnerId)</td>
                    <td class="PartialTableRowCategoryData" colspan="2">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.AssessProName)</td>
                </tr>
                @foreach (Models.ExemptionApplicationOwner item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td class="PartialTableRowData">
                           <a class="DMVLabelsTexts" href="Index/?handler=DisplayOwnerInfo&value=@item.ExemptionApplicationOwnerId">@item.ExemptionApplicationOwnerId</a>
                        </td>
                        <td class="PartialTableRowMultipleData">@item.FirstName</td>
                        <td class="PartialTableRowMultipleData">@item.LastName</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
}
else
{
    <p>No owner data available</p>
}
    <script>
        $('#OwnerNav a').click(function (e) {
              $('#ApplicationDmvResult').hide().load($(this).attr('href'), function () {
                  $('#ApplicationDmvResult').show()
              })
              return false
        })
    </script>
```

_DisplayDMVPartial.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.ExemptionApplicationDmvinformation>

@if (Model.Count() != 0)
{
    <div id="DmvNav">
        <table style=" border: 1px solid black;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2" style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center;">DMV Information</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.DmvDob)</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.DriverLicense)</td>
                </tr>
                @foreach (Models.ExemptionApplicationDmvinformation item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <!-- <td style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center;">item.DmvDob.Value.ToString("MMddyyyy")</td> -->
                        <td style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center;">@item.DmvDob</td>
                        <td style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center;">@item.DriverLicense</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
}
else
{
    <p>No owner data available</p>
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0):

Before check the demo, you need to know one thing, if your `DateOfBirth` is type of Datetime, you need be sure or convert it to format `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm`. Otherwise, you could only set value for the `type=datetime-local` input without displaying the value.

Here is a simple demo about how to autofill the textbox value by clicking your table link:

Index.cshtml:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
<form class="mt-0" method="get">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4" id="ApplicationOwnerResult">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<div class="row">
    <form class="mt-0" method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <label class="col-2 offset-4 col-form-label">Date of Birth:</label>
            <div class="col-2">
                <input class="form-control" title="Date of birth" oninput="validate()" asp-for="DateOfBirth">
                <span asp-validation-for="DateOfBirth"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
            <label class="col-2 offset-4 col-form-label">Driver's License Number:</label>
            <div class="col-2">
                <input class="form-control" title="Driver's license number" oninput="validate()" asp-for="DriversLicenseNumber">
                <span asp-validation-for="DriversLicenseNumber"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        //used to render the partial view _DisplayOwnerPartial.cshtml....
        $(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Index?handler=DisplayOwner",
                type: "Get",
                //headers: { RequestVerificationToken: $('input: hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
                success: function (data) { $("#ApplicationOwnerResult").html(data); }
            });
        })
        //auto fill the inputs...
        function DisplayInfo(id) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "Index/?handler=DisplayOwnerInfo&value="+id,
                type: "Get",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#DateOfBirth").val(data.dateOfBirth);
                    $("#DriversLicenseNumber").val(data.driversLicenseNumber);
                }

            })
        }
    </script>
}
```

_DisplayOwnerPartial.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.ExemptionApplicationOwner>

@if (Model.Count() != 0)
{
    <div id="OwnerNav">
        <table class="PartialTable">
            <tbody>
            @foreach (Models.ExemptionApplicationOwner item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td class="PartialTableRowData">
                            <a class="DMVLabelsTexts" onclick="DisplayInfo('@item.ExemptionApplicationOwnerId')" >@item.ExemptionApplicationOwnerId</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
}
```

Index.cshtml.cs:

For easy testing, I just hard-coded the data. You can get the data from database.

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public int DriversLicenseNumber { get; set; }
    public List<ExemptionApplicationOwner> ExemptionApplicationOwners { get; set; }= new List<ExemptionApplicationOwner>()
        {
            new ExemptionApplicationOwner(){ExemptionApplicationOwnerId=1,DateOfBirth=new DateTime(1987,3,12),DriversLicenseNumber=124},
            new ExemptionApplicationOwner(){ExemptionApplicationOwnerId=2,DateOfBirth=new DateTime(1997,2,11),DriversLicenseNumber=332},
            new ExemptionApplicationOwner(){ExemptionApplicationOwnerId=3,DateOfBirth=new DateTime(1987,5,23),DriversLicenseNumber=445}
        };
    public void OnGet()
    {
        
    }
    public IActionResult OnGetDisplayOwner()
    {            
        return Partial("_DisplayOwnerPartial", ExemptionApplicationOwners);
    }
    public JsonResult OnGetDisplayOwnerInfo(int value)
    {
        var data = ExemptionApplicationOwners.Where(a => a.ExemptionApplicationOwnerId == value).First();
        return new JsonResult(new { DateOfBirth =data.DateOfBirth.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm"), DriversLicenseNumber=data.DriversLicenseNumber });
    }        
}
```

Comment: this is still not working, nowhere in your example do I see the information regarding the 3rd table information, there's no call anywhere to the 3rd model

Comment: Hi @TheGame1083, how to know what is your 3rd model from your original post..... Please share more detailed code with us.

Comment: it's listed in the question DMV Partial Page

Comment: Hi @TheGame1083, what I shared is just a sample about your title said,  I just hard-coded the value to let you know how to bind them to the input. For how do they come from, you need share more details. How does your model design? Do they have any relationship? We all do not know. If you just want to call the `ExemptionApplicationDmvinformation` data from database, just call it like `_context. ExemptionApplicationDmvinformation.Where(xxx).First()` and replace my code of line `var data` in `OnGetDisplayOwnerInfo` , what's the problem? You issue is how to autofill the input by clicking the link.

Comment: Hi @Rena I have added the model code for the properties I need autofilled

Comment: Hi @Chen I have updated the code to include all the models and Db context as well

Comment: Hi @TheGame1083, Maybe you do not understand what I said. You said there is no call anywhere to the 3rd model, but you do not said how do you want to call it. In my code, just hard-coded the model data for your original issue. But what you said should be another issue. I think you can tell us how do you want to get the 3rd model.

Answer (score 0):

I made the adjustments per Renas comments and I'm still having an issue with the values not autofilling. When I run the page, and click on the value in the partial table nothing happens with the onclick event. I set the style of the anchor element to cursor: pointer,  below are the changes I made. Debugging the code as shown in the images, the values populate correctly they just do not appear in the textboxes

index.cshtml

```
@page "{id?}"
@model IndexModel

@{ViewData["Title"] = "Test";}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="text-center">
            <h1 class="display-4">@Model.PageTitle</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <form class="mt-0" method="get">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-3 offset-1" id="ApplicationResult">
                </div>
                <div class="col-4" id="ApplicationOwnerResult">
                </div>
                <div class="col-3" id="ApplicationDmvResult">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <form class="mt-0" method="post">
            <div class="row">
                <label class="col-2 offset-4 col-form-label">Date of Birth:</label>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <input class="form-control" title="Date of birth" oninput="validate()" asp-for="DateOfBirth">
                    <span asp-validation-for="DateOfBirth"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
                <label class="col-2 offset-4 col-form-label">Driver's License Number:</label>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <input class="form-control" title="Driver's license number" oninput="validate()" asp-for="DriversLicenseNumber">
                    <span asp-validation-for="DriversLicenseNumber"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-dark col-1 offset-5" type="submit" id="Submit" disabled asp-page-handler="Submit">Submit</button>
                &nbsp;
                <button class="btn btn-outline-dark col-1" type="button" id="Reset" onclick="clearAll()">Reset</button>
            </div>
            <br>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
<script>
// Any exemption applications found will be displayed when the page initially loads. On POST request GET form will be hidden
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ("@Model.Exist" == "DivIsVisible") {
            $.ajax({
                url: "Index/?handler=Display",
                type: "GET",
                data: { value: @Model.Id },
                headers: { RequestVerificationToken: $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
                success: function (data) { $("#ApplicationResult").html(data); }
            });
        }
        else {
            $("#ApplicationResult").hide();
        }
    });

// autofill the inputs
    function displayOwnerInfo(id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "Index/?handler=DisplayOwnerInfo&value=" + id,
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data) { $("#DateOfBirth").val(data.DateOfBirth); $("#DriversLicenseNumber").val(data.DriversLicenseNumber); }
        });
    }
</script>
}
```

index.cshtml.cs

```
using DMVServiceReference;
using DMV.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DMV.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public Assess50Context _context;

        // Id property refers to checking the PropertyId value for the URL
        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)] public int Id { get; set; }
        // Exist property refers to checking if GetDivs exist on POST request
        [BindProperty] public string PageTitle { get; set; } = "Residency Check";
        public ResidencyCheckCriteria CheckCriteria { get; set; }
        [BindProperty, DataMember, MaxLength(8, ErrorMessage = " "), MinLength(8, ErrorMessage = " "), RegularExpression(@"^([0-9]{8}$)", ErrorMessage = " "), Required(ErrorMessage = " ")] public string DateOfBirth { get => CheckCriteria.DateOfBirth; set => CheckCriteria.DateOfBirth = value; }
        [BindProperty, DataMember, MaxLength(13, ErrorMessage = " "), MinLength(13, ErrorMessage = " "), RegularExpression(@"^([A-Za-z0-9]{13}$)", ErrorMessage = " "), Required(ErrorMessage = " ")] public string DriversLicenseNumber { get => CheckCriteria.DriverLicenseNumber; set => CheckCriteria.DriverLicenseNumber = value; }
        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)] public string Exist { get; set; } = "DivIsVisible";

        public IndexModel(Assess50Context context)
        {
            _context = context;
            CheckCriteria = new ResidencyCheckCriteria();
        }

        // Reads all exemption application table information by property id
        public PartialViewResult OnGetDisplay(int value) => Partial("_DisplayApplicationPartial", _context.ExemptionApplications.Where(x => x.PropertyId == value).ToList());

        // Reads all exemption application owner information by exemption application id
        public PartialViewResult OnGetDisplayOwner(int value) => Partial("_DisplayOwnerPartial", _context.ExemptionApplicationOwners.Where(x => x.ExemptionApplicationId == value).GroupBy(x => x.ExemptionApplicationOwnerId).Select(x => x.First()).ToList());

        // Reads the dmv information by application owner ID
        // public PartialViewResult OnGetDisplayOwnerInfo(int value) => Partial("_DisplayDMVPartial", _context.ExemptionApplicationDmvinformations.Where(x => x.ExemptionApplicationOwnerId == value).ToList());
        public JsonResult OnGetDisplayOwnerInfo(int value)
        {
            ExemptionApplicationDmvinformation data = _context.ExemptionApplicationDmvinformations.Where(x => x.ExemptionApplicationOwnerId == value).First();
            return new JsonResult(new { DateOfBirth = data.DmvDob.ToString(), DriversLicenseNumber = data.DriverLicense });
        }
```

DbContext.cs

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace DMV.Models
{
    public partial class Assess50Context : DbContext
    {
        public virtual DbSet<ExemptionApplication> ExemptionApplications { get; set; } = null!;
  public virtual DbSet<ExemptionApplicationDmvinformation> ExemptionApplicationDmvinformations { get; set; } = null!;
 public virtual DbSet<ExemptionApplicationOwner> ExemptionApplicationOwners { get; set; } = null!;

 public Assess50Context() {}

        public Assess50Context(DbContextOptions<Assess50Context> options) : base(options) {}

 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
  }

        partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Application.cs model

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace DMV.Models
{
    public partial class ExemptionApplication
    {
        public int PropertyId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Year")] public short YearId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "App ID")] public int ExemptionApplicationId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Reference Number")] public string? ApplicationReference { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Owner.cs model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace DMV.Models
{
    public partial class ExemptionApplicationOwner
    {
        public int PropertyId { get; set; }
        public int ExemptionApplicationId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Application Owner ID")] public int ExemptionApplicationOwnerId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Owner ID")] public int? OwnerId { get; set; }
        public string? FirstName { get; set; }
        public string? LastName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Name")]public string? AssessProName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

DmvInformation.cs model

```
using SoapCore.ServiceModel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace DMV.Models
{
    public partial class ExemptionApplicationDmvinformation
    {
        public int PropertyId { get; set; }
        public int ExemptionApplicationId { get; set; }
        public int ExemptionApplicationOwnerId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "DOB")] public DateTime? DmvDob { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Driver's License #")] public string? DriverLicense { get; set; }
    }
}
```

_DisplayApplicationPartial.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.ExemptionApplication>

@if (Model.Count() != 0)
 {
    <div id="ExemptionApplicationNav">
        <table class="PartialTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="PartialTableRowData" colspan="3">Exemption Applications</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="PartialTableRowCategoryData">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.YearId)</td>
                    <td class="PartialTableRowCategoryData">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.ApplicationReference)</td>
                    <td class="PartialTableRowCategoryData">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.ExemptionApplicationId)</td>
                </tr>
                @foreach (Models.ExemptionApplication item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td class="PartialTableRowData">@item.YearId</td>
                        <td class="PartialTableRowData">@item.ApplicationReference</td>
                        <td class="PartialTableRowData">
                            <a class="DMVLabelsTexts" href="Index/?handler=DisplayOwner&value=@item.ExemptionApplicationId">@item.ExemptionApplicationId</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
 }
else
{
    <p>No exemption applications found for this Property ID</p>
}
    <script>
        $('#ExemptionApplicationNav a').click(function (e) {
            $('#ApplicationOwnerResult').hide().load($(this).attr('href'), function () {
                $('#ApplicationOwnerResult').show()
            })
            return false
        })
    </script>
```

_DisplayOwnerPartial.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.ExemptionApplicationOwner>

@if (Model.Count() != 0)
{
    <div id="OwnerNav">
        <table class="PartialTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="PartialTableRowData" colspan="3">Owner Information</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="PartialTableRowCategoryData">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.ExemptionApplicationOwnerId)</td>
                    <td class="PartialTableRowCategoryData" colspan="2">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.AssessProName)</td>
                </tr>
                @foreach (Models.ExemptionApplicationOwner item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td class="PartialTableRowData">
                           <a class="DMVLabelsTexts" onclick="displayOwnerInfo('@item.ExemptionApplicationOwnerId')">@item.ExemptionApplicationOwnerId</a>
                      <!-- <a class="DMVLabelsTexts" href="Index/?handler=DisplayOwnerInfo&value=@item.ExemptionApplicationOwnerId">@item.ExemptionApplicationOwnerId</a> -->
                        </td>
                        <td class="PartialTableRowMultipleData">@item.FirstName</td>
                        <td class="PartialTableRowMultipleData">@item.LastName</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
}
else
{
    <p>No owner data available</p>
}
 <!--
    <script>
        $('#OwnerNav a').click(function (e) {
              $('#ApplicationDmvResult').hide().load($(this).attr('href'), function () {
                  $('#ApplicationDmvResult').show()
              })
              return false
        })
    </script>
-->
```

_DisplayDMVPartial.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.ExemptionApplicationDmvinformation>

@if (Model.Count() != 0)
{
    <div id="DmvNav">
        <table style=" border: 1px solid black;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2" style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center;">DMV Information</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.DmvDob)</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.DriverLicense)</td>
                </tr>
                @foreach (Models.ExemptionApplicationDmvinformation item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <!-- <td style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center;">item.DmvDob.Value.ToString("MMddyyyy")</td> -->
                        <td style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center;">@item.DmvDob</td>
                        <td style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center;">@item.DriverLicense</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
}
else
{
    <p>No owner data available</p>
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Chen I updated all the code for you to check it out

Comment: Hi, if you have other new issue, pls post a new thread and do not make it as an answer here which is the principle in Stackoverflow.